# Multiple contact forms different receiver(s)

Tags: plugin-contactform

The current site that im building has multiple contact forms. The forms are page specific and should send this to a different user (depends on which page the user sends the form).

My question: is there a way to define per form (page) to which receiver the form should be sent?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

No. It's currently not possible, but you could make this a feature request! If you don't have the time, you could fork the plugin and make the changes yourself.